# Sign of a trigonometric sum

Tags: functions, trigonometry, fourier-series

I would like to prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}\ge 0$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^\star$ and $x\in[0,\pi]$

**EDIT** : Thanks for the references. The result of Leopold Vietoris gives a nice extension of the Fejer-Jackson's inequality. I could not find more than the statement of his theorem ... Does anyone know where to find it (or at least a sketch of it) ?

I also found (somewhere on the net and without any proof) the following assertion (which seems true, according to a few plottings ...)

> For all $n\in\mathbb{N}^\star$ and $x\in(0,\pi)$, we have :
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}\ge x\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^3$$

**If true**, this result would give yet another proof of FJ's inequality. Any hints ?

Comment: That is the Fejer-Jackson inequality. A bit of Googling will help for sure.

Comment: i think a proof was found by Vietoris an Austrian mathematician

Comment: Thank you. Just edited the OP.